# Scanning different types of variables in one line

Tags: java, string, java.util.scanner

As the title says, I would like to scan the whole line of input just using one input from user. The input should be like "Eric 22 1".

If `nextString()` shouldn't be used that way, should I just use `hasNext`?

JAVA CODE :

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class tugas1
{
    public static void main(String []args)
    {
        String name;
        int age;
        boolean sex;

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Please input your name, age, and sex(input 1 if you are a male, or 0 if you are a female) :");
        name = sc.nextString();
        age = sc.nextInt();
        sex = sc.nextBoolean();

        if(isString(name))
        {
            if(isInteger(age))
            {
                if(isBoolean(sex))
                {
                    System.out.println("Correct format. You are :" +name);
                }
                else
                {
                    System.out.println("Please input the age in integer");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("Please input the age in integer");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Please input the name in string");
        }
    }
}
```

After adding and editing the lines :

```
System.out.println("Please input your name, age, and sex(input 1 if you are a male, or 0 if you are a female) :");
    String input = sc.nextLine();

String[] inputAfterSplit = input.split(" ");

String name = inputAfterSplit[0];
int age = Integer.parseInt(inputAfterSplit[1]);
boolean sex = Boolean.parseBoolean(inputAfterSplit[2]);
```

I would like to add if(name instanceof String). I haven't touched Java since a long time and I forgot is that the way of using instanceof, or is that wrong?
The point is I want to compare if the input var is in int or string or bool.

```
if(name instanceof String)
{
    if(age instanceof Integer)
    {
        if(sex instanceof Boolean)
        {    
            System.out.println("All checked out")
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Not boolean")
        }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("Not int")
    }

System.out.println("Not string")
}
```

Will these lines work?

Comment: It's just called `next()`, not `nextString()`.

Comment: Thanks! So the other nextblahblah() is correct?
nextInt(), nextBoolean() is ok?

Comment: Well, sure.  The documentation is at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html  I think `nextBoolean` looks for `true` or `false`; and since you have `1` or `0`, it might be better to use `nextInt`, and then convert it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Please input your name, age, and sex

As you need to insert values in specific sequence.

---

Use `nextLine()` and perform `split`

For Example:`"Abc 123 true 12.5 M"`

```
String s[]=line.split(" ");
```

And you will have

```
s[0]="Abc"
s[1]="123"
s[2]="true"
s[3]="12.5"
s[4]="M"
```

Than parse them to required type.

```
String first=s[0];
int second=Integer.parseInt(s[1].trim());
boolean third=Boolean.parseBoolean(s[2].trim());
double forth=Double.parseDouble(s[3].trim());
char fifth=s[4].charAt(0);
```

---

*As your code suggest and as `David` said you can change just this*

```
    name = sc.next();//will read next token
    age = sc.nextInt();
    sex = (sc.next()).charAt(0);//change sex to character for M and F
    //or //sex = sc.nextInt();//change it to int
```

Comment: Wow thanks, now I know better about trim() usage..
But I just couldn't get it working because of silly mistake which I just discovered why lol.

Comment: @KaeM Great!! No problem if my answer provides solution  you can accept my answer by clicking the tick next to it.. thanks.

Comment: Why would you bother using `split` and `trim`, when a `Scanner` lets you read each field individually?  The OP's original strategy was better than this - he/she just unfortunately had the method name wrong.

Comment: @DavidWallace Oh yeas Sorry!!! I was wrong `Scanning different types of variables in one line` title take my thought process to split.You can downvote my answer if you want and KaeM you can unaccept answer as well if you want to :)

Comment: No, it's not really bad enough for a downvote.  You might want to change `nextBoolean()` to `nextInt()` though, and do something to convert `0` or `1` to the required value.  `nextBoolean` can only read `"true"` or `"false"`.

Comment: Oh right! Bool can only read true or false, thanks!
Maybe I should change it to string too so I just have to use next()..
My instructors instructions were to use bool as the third variable's type..
Addition, how to detect each input's data type?? Like if it's integer, the input is shown, whereas if it's not, then it will say that the data isn't integer

Comment: That's what `hasNextInt()` is for.

Answer (score 0):

first thing when we use `scanner` , we dont have a method called `nextString()`

so instead we must use `next()` which is to read string.

secondly when you want to read whole line then use `nextLine()` which will read entire line in the form of text and put it in a string.

now the `String` which is read as `entire line` can be `split` based on split character(assume it is space in our case)

then get the `string array` and `parse` each element to required type.

better if we use `try/catch` while parsing so that we can catch exception for unwanted format for the input and throw it to user.

sample code without try/catch but you use try/catch as per your need

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Please input your name, age, and sex(input 1 if you are a male, or 0 if you are a female) :");
      String input = sc.nextLine();

      String[] inputAfterSplit = input.split(" ");

      String firstParam = inputAfterSplit[0];
      int secondParam=Integer.parseInt(inputAfterSplit[1]);
      boolean thirdParam=Boolean.parseBoolean(inputAfterSplit[2]);
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!
I used your variable names so that it would be clearer for myself, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Reworked it all, this is the remake of the code just in case people are having same problem as mine..
int in the delcaration should be changed into Integer

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.lang.*;

public class tugas1
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Input number of line :");
    int lineNum = sc.nextInt();

    String[] name = new String[lineNum];
    Integer[] age = new Integer[lineNum];
    String[] gender = new String[lineNum];

    System.out.println("Please input your name, age, and gender(Male/Female) \n(Separate each line by an enter) :");
    for ( int i = 0; i < lineNum; i++)
    {
        System.out.print("Line " + (i+1) + " : ");
        name[i] = sc.next();
        age[i] = sc.nextInt();
        gender[i] = sc.next();
    }

    for ( int j = 0; j < lineNum; j++ )
    {
        if (name[j] instanceof String)
        {
            if (age[j] instanceof Integer)
            {
                if (gender[j] instanceof String)
                {
                    System.out.println("Person #" + (j+1) +  " is " + name[j] + ", with age of " + age[j] + " years old, and gender " + gender[j]);
                }
                else
                {
                    System.out.println("Gender is missing");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("Age and Gender are");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Name, Age and Gender are missing");
        }
    }
}
```

}